# luigi - how to create a dependency not between files, but between tasks? (or how to not involve the output method)

Tags: python, python-2.7, luigi

Given two luigi tasks, how can I add one as a requirement for the other, in a way that if the required is done, the second task could start, with no output involved?

Currently I get **RuntimeError: Unfulfilled dependency at run time: MyTask___home_...** even though the task completed ok, because my `requires / output` methods are not configured right...

```
class ShellTask(ExternalProgramTask):
    """
    ExternalProgramTask's subclass dedicated for one task with the capture output ability.

    Args:
        shell_cmd (str): The shell command to be run in a subprocess.
        capture_output (bool, optional): If True the output is not displayed to console,
                                         and printed after the task is done via 
                                         logger.info (both stdout + stderr).
                                         Defaults to True.
    """
    shell_cmd = luigi.Parameter()
    requirement = luigi.Parameter(default='')
    succeeded = False

    def on_success(self):
        self.succeeded = True

    def requires(self):
        return eval(self.requirement) if self.requirement else None

    def program_args(self):
        """
        Must be implemented in an ExternalProgramTask subclass.
        Returns:
            A script that would be run in a subprocess.Popen.
        Args:
            shell_cmd (luigi.Parameter (str)): the shell command to be passed as args
                                               to the run method (run should not be overridden!).
        """
        return self.shell_cmd.split()


class MyTask(ShellTask):
    """
    Args:    if __name__ == '__main__':
    clean_output_files(['_.txt'])
    task = MyTask(
            shell_cmd='...',
            requirement="MyTask(shell_cmd='...', output_file='_.txt')",
            )
    """
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    task_0 = MyTask(
            shell_cmd='...',
            requirement="MyTask(shell_cmd='...')",
            )
    luigi.build([task_0], workers=2, local_scheduler=False)
```

I hoped using the `on_success` could prompt something to the caller task, but I didn't figure out how to.

I'm currently overcoming this in the following way:

```
0) implement the output method based on the input of the task (much like the eval(requirement) I did
2) implement the run method (calling the super run and then writing "ok" to output
3) deleting the output files from main.
4) calling it somehitng like this:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clean_output_files(['_.txt'])
    task = MyTask(
            shell_cmd='...',
            requirement="MyTask(shell_cmd='...', output_file='_.txt')",
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

So within your first luigi task, you could call your second Task within by making it a requirement.

For example:

```
class TaskB(luigi.Task):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.complete_flag = False
  def run(self):
      self.complete_flag = True
      print('do something')

   def complete(self):
      return self.is_complete

class TaskA(luigi.Task):
   def requires(self):
      return TaskB()

   def run(self):
      print('Carry on with other logic')
```

Comment: That gives the same error. Task 0 is requiring Task 1 to run, and returns it from the `requires()` but since Task 1 does not return anything and doesn't do anything special in its `run / output` methods, Task 0 thinks it failed